# How to read binary data on Kafka topics in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I need to read an encrypted message from a Kafka topic. My current code which reads strings from the topic looks like this :

```
JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> pairrdd = 
            KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc, zkQuorum, group, topicmap);
```

What should I do to change this code from the kafka queue to make sure that the array of bytes read, the encrypted data is not corrupted

Comment: Well...`<byte[], byte[]>` would be a good start

Answer (score 1):

For reading data from Kafka in `<byte[], byte[]>` form, you can use `KafkaUtils`. Like this-

```
Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092,anotherhost:9092");
kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", ByteArrayDeserializer.class);
kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", ByteArrayDeserializer.class);
kafkaParams.put("group.id", "use_a_separate_group_id_for_each_stream");
kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", false);

Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList("topicA", "topicB");

JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]>> pairrdd =
  KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
    jssc,
    LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
    ConsumerStrategies.<byte[], byte[]>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams)
  );
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: @kevin What's the issue?

Comment: Well, the data in my kafka is a binary message, and I want to read it in sparkstreaming, and then parse it in bytes.

Comment: @kevin, in that case, you can use `ByteArrayDeserializer` instead of `StringDeserializer`. I have updated my answer accordingly.